# Getting Numeric overflow error for smaller numbers but success for larger numbers

Tags: oracle, plsql

Following is my test function:

```
create or replace FUNCTION test
RETURN NUMBER
AS
  v_count   number(15);
  v_msisdn  number(15);
BEGIN
  v_msisdn:= 225952 * 10000;
  -- v_msisdn:=50510060853 * 10000;

  return v_msisdn;
END;
```

When I execute the function as

```
select test() from dual;
```

I get an error

```
1426. 00000 -  "numeric overflow"
*Cause:    Evaluation of an value expression causes an overflow/underflow.
```

However, if I update

```
v_msisdn:=50510060853 * 10000;
```

I do not get error.

Could some one please explain this behaviour as the second query is a bigger number?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can fix this by casting one of the integer literals to `integer` or `number`:

```
v_msisdn:= cast(225952 as integer) * 10000;
```

Small integer literals are treated like [`pls_integer`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/datatypes.htm#LNPLS99938) for performance reasons. Unfortunately, this type raises an exception on overflow:

> A calculation with two PLS_INTEGER values that overflows the PLS_INTEGER range raises an overflow exception, even if you assign the result to a NUMBER data type  For calculations outside the PLS_INTEGER range, use INTEGER, a predefined subtype of the NUMBER data type.

In your second example, one of the values (50510060853) doesn't fit into the range of `pls_integer` and, thus, is interpreted as an `integer`.

Here's the similar question on AskTom: [Datatype Number results in Numeric overflow although value is small enough](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:9531631800346339791)